# Assign a default value to a variable symfony2 annotation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

how I can assign (cuurent_time) a default value to a variable ($dateajout)

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dateajout", type="datetime" , nullable=true)
 */
private $dateajout;
```

Comment: Please show an effort to solve the issue on your own. Include how you did so, and the results. Simply quoting code and asking how it's done is off-topic for StackOverflow. [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
class Dummy
{

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dateajout", type="datetime" , nullable=true)
     */
    private $dateajout;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dateajout = new \DateTime();
    }

}
```

?